# What is the difference between saving Keras model with extension .h5 and extension .hdf5?

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, hdf

Is there a difference between saving the Keras model with the extension `.h5` and extension `.hdf5`?

In other words, is there a difference between those two lines of code `model.save('model.h5')` and `model.save('model.hdf5')` assuming that I have a Keras model named `model` in my code?

Comment: the models(HDF5 version) are saved as an .h5 or .hdf5 format.

Comment: So, what is the purpose of creating two extensions for the same file format? I think there should be any minor difference.

Answer (score 1):

An `H5` file is a data file saved in the `Hierarchical Data Format (HDF)`. Files saved in the `HDF5 version` are saved as an `H5` or `HDF5` file.

The extension is used so that people and applications can identify the file format from the name, so either can be used.
It is the same as there are multiple `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, etc. in jpeg format image files.